# How do you identify what capacitor to use to filter DC voltage ripples from a bridge rectifier? (capacitance, etc.)

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, ripple, ripple-current

Let's say I have reduced 220V 60Hz AC to 1.5V 750mA AC with a step-down transformer and used a bridge rectifier consisting of 4 IN4007 diodes to convert it to DC. How do I math this down?

Comment: How much ripple do you want to allow?

Comment: enough to not destroy a cheap wall clock

Comment: Then the capacitor you need is enough to not let it be destroyed.

Comment: How much ripple can your load handle? If it can handle huge amounts of ripple, then you might not need a capacitor, but if it's very picky (e.g. a microprocessor) you might need some filtering beyond what a capacitor can do. Also, your diodes are going to be reducing your voltage significantly! 1N4007 diodes have a high voltage drop, and with a full-wave bridge rectifier you'll be losing twice the diodes' forward voltage. Don't expect to get more than half a volt out of that thing, even being optimistic about the forward voltage.

Comment: And... if this is a cheap wall clock, why on earth is it drawing 750 mA? It shouldn't be anywhere _near_ that high.

Comment: oops, forgot to note: there should be a capacitor before the rectifier that will reduce that to about 16mA..

Comment: capacitor *before*? you mean the AC side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know your average / peak load currents.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2few56s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image]

Full wave rectifier ripple voltage:

\$V_{Ripple} = I_{Load}/(Freq * C) \$

Were \$Freq\$ is twice the line frequency for a full wave rectifier.

Your voltage and current numbers do seem rather odd though.